# Django First Tutorial: ImportError: No module named 'polls'

Tags: python, django

I've set up Django on my Windows 10 PC, and was working through the first tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

I can't seem to do the first part, because of an import error.

Here's the views.py script:

```
mysite/polls/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

urls.py in the polls app:

```
mysite/polls/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And urls.py in mysite:

```
mysite/mysite/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

After troubleshooting and fixing issues with the first two files, this is the error I get when I run "python urls.py" on the mysite urls.py file:

[image]

I've seen a few stackoverflow posts here regarding this tutorial, and similar issues. Someone advocated that I add polls to the INSTALLED_APPS section of settings.py, but this did not work.

```
/mysite/mysite/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
```

I also read that someone got this to work by adding the 'polls' module to their pythonpath... But I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

A very similar post was made here: [Django reusable apps tutorial, ImportError: No module named 'polls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785902/django-reusable-apps-tutorial-importerror-no-module-named-polls)
but no solution was provided.

Anyone with some insight or input, please let me know what I can do to fix this, and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Why would you "run python urls.py"? What in the tutorial tells you to do that? Don't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wasn't getting any error output when I ran "python manage.py runserver", but the url was still not working. So I had to do that with each file to ensure there were no python errors.

Comment: But it's just not something you should expect to work, so I don't know why you are asking a question about it.

Comment: I was just trying to root out python errors. Ultimately, my goal is to run "python manage.py runserver", and be able to see something when I go to localhost:8000/polls, which is not happening right now.

Comment: You should post the error you see at /polls, then.

Comment: That's kind of the issue... In my browser, it simply says "Connection refused". No other detail. And my terminal doesn't say anything either.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running `urls.py`. shouldn't you be running `python manage.py runserver` command to start the app. Are you trying to achieve something else here ?

Comment: I was just doing that to troubleshoot the individual file. My real problem is, when I run "python manage.py runserver", and then go to localhost:8000/polls/, I get an error.